# How to apply RatingBar border without using an image?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, ratingbar

I wanted to create a `RatingBar` that does not use an image to have a border. But I can't seem to get it right.

Here's what I wanted it to look like:

[image: with border]

Here's what I got (filled - half empty - empty):

[image: filled - half empty - empty]

Here's my layout:

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingbar_rate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:rating="2.5"
    android:stepSize="0.5"
    android:scaleX="3.5"
    android:scaleY="3.5"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
    android:isIndicator="false"
    android:progressTint="@color/star"
    android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/star_border"
    android:secondaryProgressTint="@color/star_partially_empty"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/star_partially_empty"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe any of these additional libraries: http://android-arsenal.com/tag/84

would do a disired work for you. Notice, that some of these doesn't use image.

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I used a custom drawable `layer-list` and Android will be the one to do the rest.

My `RatingBar`:

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingbar_rate"
    style="@style/rateUsBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:rating="0"
    android:stepSize="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
/>
```

In `styles.xml`:

```
<resources>
    ...
    ...
    <style name="rateUsBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/rating_stars</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/rate_us_star_minheight</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">@dimen/rate_us_star_maxheight</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

In `rating_stars.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/rate_empty" /> //gray star for empty
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/rate_empty" /> //gray star for empty
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/rate_filled" /> //yellow star for filled
</layer-list>
```

In `dimens.xml`:

```
<resources>
    ...
    ...
    <dimen name="rate_us_star_minheight"> <!--height of your image--> </dimen>
    <dimen name="rate_us_star_maxheight"> <!--height of your image--> </dimen>
</resources>
```

And that's it!